# How to extend SimpleXMLRPCServer so that child class registers some functions?

Tags: python, inheritance, simplexmlrpcserver

I am learning python just now and trying to make a simple XML-RPC server. The examples in Python documentation show this:

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler

# Restrict to a particular path.
class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

# Create server
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000),
                            requestHandler=RequestHandler)
server.register_introspection_functions()

# Register pow() function; this will use the value of
# pow.__name__ as the name, which is just 'pow'.
server.register_function(pow)


# Run the server's main loop
server.serve_forever()
```

So what I would like to do is extend `SimpleXMLRPCServer` as `MyXMLRPC` that sets some of it's methods as the server methods. These are meant to be object methods, not just static/class ones, therefore they must be able to manipulate with the `MyXMLRPC` instance data. I think this will somewhat make use of this functionality:

```
# Register an instance; all the methods of the instance are
# published as XML-RPC methods (in this case, just 'div').
class MyFuncs:
    def div(self, x, y):
        return x // y
server.register_instance(MyFuncs())
```

But of course I just want to register some methods and, also, I really need to do this within constructor of `MyXMLRPC`. How do I do it?